# Is there a program that can reliably transfer installed software and application data from one computer to the other?

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, backup, disk-cloning

I have had some OS corruption in Windows 8.1 that is causing random reboots when copying files to/from USB and I am hoping that I can perform a clean install and cut out the part where I have to reinstall the many hundreds of installed programs and games. I have seen stuff like this advertised before, but I have always been skeptical of whether they actually work. 
EDIT: Luckily a combination of DISM and SFC appears to have fixed the corruption. Some of the system files involved with the Background Intelligent Transfer Service had been corrupted and so that (and maybe Readyboost?) was doing something funky with USB drives that was forcing a reboot.

Comment: Most applications don’t require being installed to function.  If you want to be able to uninstall them, then installing them, really is the only solution

Comment: If you bought the game on Steam, it has a simple backup and restore function.

Comment: There is no program that will work in ALL cases.

Comment: If you have exactly the same hardware and you want to duplicate an installed system I recommend [Acronis Backup](https://www.acronis.com/de-de/business/backup/). Tested it with multiple systems in a commercial environment. But this was with a fresh installation, only the programs we wanted to have and exactly the same hardware components in the other systems.

Comment: I used Acronis True Image extensively back in the day for disk cloning before I switched to Paragon Drive Copy (the most powerful option IMO at least back in 2014). I liked it. Funny you mention their backup solution, a good friend and fellow IT admin recently started using it and he absolutely swears by it. Maybe I will look into trying a trial of it.

Answer (score 4):

Although there are other answers here.

The short and honest answer is NO.

There is nothing that can reliably transfer applications to a new operating system. Applications are built and configured to work on the operating system they were originally installed on. Many changes are made that are dependent on other components of the OS. For this reason, you can't reliably move an application even if you could figure out how to grab the thousands of files and registry keys.

The primary reason for reinstalling your OS or starting fresh is to have a computer that runs well. If you want your programs to run reliable as well, then you also reinstall them fresh.

There is nothing wrong with backing up data, and transferring settings. There are many programs that do that. But, you should be selective with this as well, because many malicious applications/plugins will move with it. Think of it this way, if Chrome was acting screwy on the old computer, then if you migrate all those settings and plugins to a new computer, it's going to be screwy on the new computer.

If you choose to do a data/settings migration, Microsoft already provides full functionality to do that with their [user state migration tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-overview) - no 3rd party software needed. Microsoft recommends a 3rd party (paid) application called PCmover. But, there is no reason USMT can't be used even as a one off if you are so inclined to learn how to use it. But, you only do this after reinstalling all the 3rd party software fresh so that it matches the installed software on the old computer.

It may be time consuming to reinstall software, but your patience and effort will be rewarded. You'll also find out what you truly need and what you probably hardly ever touch.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as off topic by Ramhound, I think this is a perfectly valid question, there ARE legitimate programs that advertise this and I want to know if anyone has tried them.

Comment: Here is a great example: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/migrate-OS-to-SSD/

Comment: @Braden'sPC's Your welcome. The software you linked to appears to just be a cloning software. The reason why this is off topic is because it is asking for software recommendations.  To refine the question, just ask if it’s possible to do, rather than asking for software solutions. See her: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I accidentally linked to the wrong program. Here is what I was going for: https://www.easeus.com/free-pc-transfer-software/

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but I got a free copy through work. Lucky for me, the whole reason I was looking into this was OS corruption and a combination of DISM and SFC appears to have fixed that issue. Thank god.

Answer (score 2):

http://ppc.laplink.com/specialpages/pcmover-vs-wet-chart-us/

PC Mover can move application, but your mileage will vary.

Some applications will be fine, and other may not be.

---

This depend on how you define transfer.

If you want to duplicate the whole PC **exactly** then cloning to the rescue.  IE imaging a classroom full of computers.

It is best to **sysprep /generalize /oobe** is recommended to regenerate the SID prior to the first clone deployment.

I have done this hundreds of times and cloning works!

Clonezilla and drbl are great options.

1. Clone orginal to another hdd  as image1
2. sysprep /generalize /oobe
3. Clone to another hdd as image-final
4. Restore the image on as many computer as you are licensed for.

Note:  Sysprep is very finicky, and the tiniest errors can break your image.  This is where you jump for joy you made a backup in step 1.  Restore backup, and try again.  Deleting or renaming any **unattend.xml** found in the c:\windows\system32\sysprep folder often helps.  Starting with Windows 8 with the windows store you may have to uninstall some windows store apps to get sysprep to complete successfully.

Answer (score 1):

One very easy options would be to use SAMSUNG magician, but for that you need an SSD, and EVERYBODY needs and SSD these days, so if you don't have one time to get one!

With this solution you can do it in one operation, it's insanely easy, Samsung Magician does a full back up of everything and then puts it on the new disk.

There are other options as you know, but they are touch and go.

In the future, I recommend you use portable software, no installation required, you can run a large variety of programs with that including Chrome, Firefox, open office etc...

https://portableapps.com/

Comment: I thought Samsung Magician just cloned the drive. Not quite the same thing. I will have to take a second look at that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the option in Samsung Magician, in mine I do not see a backup option (I have a SSD).

Comment: There is an extra program called [Samsung Data Migration](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201710/20171030115320828/Samsung_Data_Migration_Setup.exe) for cloning SSDs. Thanks for making me find it. Samsung Magician itself does not contain such a function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put the link in there, in my case, the software came with the drive as installation disk, I took it for granted if OP buys it, he will have it...not sure if that works for other SSDs?